# How to enforce subclasses to implement a method which accepts a certain type

Tags: java, polymorphism, hierarchy

I want to simulate Smart Devices world. My plan was to create a hierarchy like this.

Smart Device as my main interface.
Phone and Watch as classes which implement Smart Device.
and Samsung and Apple as classes which extend Phone.

and finally I have two classes named ios and android which extend a superclass named Os.

I want to have the ability to enforce apple and samsung to install their own respective Os while I enforce the installation of Os on every Device(such as watch) which implements SmartDevice.

Therefore I created a method called istallOs(Os test) in my interface but the problem is I can not implement that method in phone level because I don't know if it is samsung or apple.

I am guessing my Hierarchy is not suitable for this problem and I should move installOs to a lower level.

What is the solution to this problem? If you can include bounded Types and a sample in your solution that would be great.

```
public interface SmartDevice<T extends Os> {

  public Boolean installOs(T os);
}

public abstract class Phone implements SmartDevice<T extends Os>{

 @Override
 public Boolean installOs(T t) {
  //Cant implement it here since I dont know what device i am dealing with
 }
}

public class ApplePhone extends Phone<ios>  {

@Override
public Boolean installOs(ios os) {
  //this is an Apple phone so its ok to install ios in it.

    System.out.println("Installing Os: "+os.getName());
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the mistake is trying to implement `installOs` as a concrete method in `Phone`. Why not just leave it abstract?

Comment: You could parametrize `Phone` with `T` as well: `class Phone<T extends Os> implements SmartDevice<T> {...}`

Comment: Since OSs should probably be globally equal, you should consider using them as singleton and assign a specific OS from that singleton (eq: a Set<OS>) to a SmartDevice.

Comment: could you please send me a good tutorial on singleton ? I have heard the name before but never came across working with it.

Comment: @MohsenFM: Surely you need to test it *for any specific implementation*. Given that you don't know how to implement it in `Phone`, what are you expecting to test about it?

Comment: @MadMatts: Using a singleton sounds like a bad idea to me... using an enum would make more sense, potentially.

Comment: @JornVernee sounds like a good idea. thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes it worked. I wasn't sure i could put an abstract method in an interface.

Comment: I think I found the answer guys, I changed the `installOs` method in the Phone class to abstract and then I changed the class to this:                   `public abstract class Phone<A extends Os> implements SmartDevice<A>{

    @Override
    public abstract Boolean installOs(A s) ;`

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I could put an abstract method in my interface!

so all I needed all along was

```
public interface SmartDevice<T extends Os> {
  public abstract Boolean installOs(T os);
}
```

Then I went to the phone class and changed bounded types to this:

```
public abstract class Phone<A extends Os> implements SmartDevice<A>{

@Override
public abstract Boolean installOs(A s) ;

}
```

Thank you for your help guys.